# Converting JSON to String in Android with MySql project

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, json

I'm new on Android and I'm trying to connect my android application to my local server phpmyadmin. I've seen some tutorial about the interaction Android-MySql through PHP pages (using JSON), but I have a problem with the output (how do I convert what I obtained from JSON to String, for example?). To make you better understand the problem, this is my code:

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

This is my PHP file "get_product.php" (the DB connection works fine):

```
<?php

$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

if (isset($_GET["ID"])) {
$ID_work = $_GET['ID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID = $ID");

if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $product = array();
        $product["ID"] = $result["ID"];
        $product["title"] = $result["title"];
        $product["description"] = $result["description"];

        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["product"] = array();

        array_push($response["product"], $product);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

In the Manifest I insert internet permissions and now, in my activity I insert:

```
private static String url = "http://IP_ADDRESS/connect/get_product.php";
```

But now how can I save title and description obtained in a String?

Thank you very much indeed for your help!

@Sajmon: This is the LogCat

```
05-13 19:53:32.322: E/JSON Parser(10336): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><HEAD><TITLE> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-13 19:53:32.322: D/AndroidRuntime(10336): Shutting down VM
05-13 19:53:32.322: W/dalvikvm(10336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d578)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/package.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at package.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:158)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
05-13 19:53:32.332: E/AndroidRuntime(10336):    ... 11 more
```

and the line 158 is:

```
String title = obj.getString("title");
```

Comment: where you facing problem? First get the json and then parse it

Comment: On PHP side make sure you prevent sql injection. Use mysql_real_escape_string  everywhere you use $_GET or $_POST etc to get a variable you are going to use in a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

So you almost got it. Actually your `makeHttpRequest()` method returns `JSONObject` returned from `PHP` script.

Now you only need to parse your `JSON` and retrieve and save values from it.

Here is solution as **pseudo-code**:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject obj = parser.makeHttpRequest("GET", <url>, <params>);
// getting data from JSON
String title = obj.getString("title");
String decription = obj.getString("description");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I try as follow, but the application in my device crashes.. Where am I doing wrong? (sorry for formatting..)

Comment: public class A extends Activity {
 ..
 String ID;
    private static String url = "...";
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";

 public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
  ...
  try {
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", ID));
   JSONObject obj = parser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
   String title = obj.getString("title");
   String description = obj.getString("description");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
 ..
    }

Comment: @kareth add to your question your full logcat.

Comment: Thank you, I've posted the logcat!

Comment: @kareth you don't have valid `JSON`, look at logcat, you are getting at first `JSONException` that probably then result in `NullPointerException`.